# Flutter app not running iPhone 13 simulator on MacBook with M1 chip

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

I'm here because I've spent 2 hours trying maybe 35 solutions online with no resolution.

Any help is appreciated.

Console output when trying to run Flutter app with iPhone 13 simulator from Android Studio:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            8.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:17E0CDFE-14C8-41CF-A758-A03C2808BECD, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DF600FCE-5786-495E-8FE2-AFB4F590D17D, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:820AA3A8-2ADB-4A58-A58C-5563079343A1, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:66BA4187-152A-4BA5-87D6-620FB0E9C12A, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A50D6A6C-94C1-4EFB-B05C-2A5A4955D0C7, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:980718BF-A3EA-4913-91B3-A6A9926DF3FF, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:10363AEF-6B4D-4B01-A12A-8300E781536C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EEB0ECC8-CBF3-4C0B-8E0F-9DA8EAD3A776, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D3C0135F-4C7A-46FD-ACB3-6BF5894C94A3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F90445F-A1DF-42AE-9962-7040AE3D4346, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA8010C4-467F-419F-908A-E82B8F6EE9EC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8D8EB1FA-A788-451F-A2C6-EB84B3EC43D1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DC495BD4-9CA2-41F4-AA47-67294EE04CE9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6BE3E291-D5F7-4DCF-913E-10C1C33CD1CF, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2A6135AC-AF7F-42A8-8150-7B69C837AE6D, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DFE716FD-A148-46DA-B74E-D488E36749FB, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5F83B222-5F80-4A6A-A7EF-C48D980D9023, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9860FFF6-B08C-46D1-B31D-C978CBF32C0E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0A2855E5-DFF4-4E4D-A510-1E37D7B289F0, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F8FBAC5-7154-4DE0-AE02-35EE7E3F1FCC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A944BE5-0B40-44B5-88D7-4786EF832E9E, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-000A216101D1001E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: Have you checked `Copy items if needed` when you add `GoogleService-Info.plist` into your project as mentioned in [iOS installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios) instruction?

Comment: Are you using firebase or any google service? error looks like the info plist of google service you are using is not in right place.